# Why does do I have an IO error saying my file doesn't exist even though it does exist in the directory?

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to loop over a Python directory, and I have a specific file that happens to be the last file in the directory such that I get an `IOerror` for that specific file.

The error I get is:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nod_gyro_instance_11_P_4.csv'
```

My script:

```
for filename in os.listdir("/Users/my_name/PycharmProjects/My_Project/Data/Nod/Gyro"):
data = []
if filename.endswith(".csv"):
    data.append(k_fold(filename))
    continue
else:
    continue
```

k_fold does this:

```
def k_fold(myfile, myseed=11109, k=20):
# Load data
data = open(myfile).readlines()
```

The entire traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Users/my_name/PycharmProjects/MY_Project/Cross_validation.py", line 30, in <module>
data.append(k_fold(filename))
  File "/Users/my_name/PycharmProjects/My_Project/Cross_validation.py", line 8, in k_fold
data = open(myfile).readlines()
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nod_gyro_instance_11_P_4.csv'
```

My CSV files are such:

```
nod_gyro_instance_0_P_4.csv
nod_gyro_instance_0_P_3.csv
nod_gyro_instance_0_P_2.csv
nod_gyro_instance_0_P_5.csv

...

nod_gyro_instance_11_P_4.csv
nod_gyro_instance_10_P_6.csv
nod_gyro_instance_10_P_5.csv
nod_gyro_instance_10_P_4.csv
```

Why doesn't it recognize my `nod_gyro_instance_10_P_4.csv` file?

Comment: Have you tried to simplify it to a [MCVE] to figure out what line or collection of lines is causing the issue? All of the things having to do with random, k_fold, etc. don't seem to be expressly pertinent to the issue at hand. If you simplify it to just 3 or 4 lines that hit this issue, I can bet you'll figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: I got rid of the irrelevant k_fold information.

Comment: You didn't include the file path in your filename, try: `k_fold(os.path.join("/Users/my_name/PycharmProjects/My_Project/Data/Nod/Gyro", filename))` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.listdir` returns just filenames, not absolute paths. If you're not currently in that same directory, trying to read the file will fail.

You need to join the dirname onto the filename returned:

```
data_dir = "/Users/my_name/PycharmProjects/My_Project/Data/Nod/Gyro"
for filename in os.listdir(data_dir):
    k_fold(os.path.join(data_dir, filename))
```

Alternatively, you could use `glob` to do both the listing (with full paths) and extension filtering:

```
import glob
for filename in glob.glob("/Users/my_name/PycharmProjects/My_Project/Data/Nod/Gyro/*.csv"):
    k_fold(filename)
```